# Making XML in SQL Server faster - convert to tables?

Tags: c#, sql, xml, vb.net

I have a field in the database that is XML because it represents a class that is used in C#/VB.Net. Problem is after the initial manipulation most, but not all, of the manipulation is done in SQL Server. This means that the XML field is converted on the fly.

As we are getting more fields and more records, this operation is getting slow. I think the slow down is the converting all of those fields to other data types.

So to speed it up I was thinking of a couple of ways:

Have a set of tables that represent the different pieces of the XML data. I would make these tables read only using a trigger on Insert/Update that would reject any changes. My 'main' table with the XML in it when it updates the XML would turn off the triggers, update the tables with the new values then turn the triggers back on.

The only real reason we use the XML is because it's really easy to convert it to the class in C#/VB.Net. But I'm getting the point where I may end up writing a routine that will take all the bits and pieces and convert it to a class and also a function to go the other way (class -> tables).

Can anybody give any ideas on a better way to do this? I'm not tied to the idea of using the XML structure. My concern is if we have separate tables to speed up SQL processing and somebody changes the value of a field in that table we have to make sure the XML is updated. Or don't allow the person to update it.

TIA - Jeff.

Comment: Representing a C# class is not in itself a particularly good reason to use XML instead of relational tables.

Comment: If you are manipulating the class representation in sql, it's no longer a reliable representation and therefore a complete waste of space. Stop messing about, admit you "got" it wrong, ditch the xml, have the class load itself from the table data.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the objects you are saving? If anything other than persistence of state, you are not doing yourself any favors and you are not properly separating concerns. If they are persistence of state, then at minimum, make columns out of the properties and fields (can include private as long as you leave an internal method to set the values when you reconstitute).

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the wisdom of what you're doing, you might look into creating an XML index. This should help you get started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345121%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

The basic idea is that the right index can 'pre-shred' your XML and automatically build the sor of tables you are thinking of doing 'manually'. A downside is that this can really explode your storage requirements if you are storing lots of XML.

Comment: I think I'll have to convert it to tables instead.

Comment: I think the real problem is when I pull the records it has to 'unxml' the XML table. There are lots of things in there that we need frequently so we spend a lot of time calling a view which converts it. I'm assuming that where I'm losing all the time.

Comment: An XML index can pre-unxml an XML column for you. The article I linked explains it fairly well. If you are getting at the XML through a view, you might be outsmarting the SQL engine and making things worse?